# Is it possible to invoke the native Share function in iOS and Android via an in-page link?

Tags: android, html, ios, share

I want to put a button in-page that will invoke the new in-browser Share function in iOS and Android. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's why you have these popups asking to tap on the share button, and add it to home screen.